# Corrupt block found indicating potential hardware failure; shutting down

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am experiencing issues with both Bitcoin Core 0.20 & 0.22 on my 2020 iMac per the title.  I have run diagnostics (shutdown and +D) and on black startup screen it says "No Issues found. Reference code ADP000".
The size of Application Support\Bitcoin\Chainstate is "4,571,371,737 bytes (4.58 GB on disk) for 2,287 items".  I have a 2TB hard disk with 1.2TB used (so plenty of space). The last time I had an issue like this I deleted and reloaded the Blockchain from scratch but cant recall the exact steps.  As I have a relatively fast uncapped fibre connection so comfortable to reload from 2010.  I am stuck at the block 702544 of July 28 2021 at 16:54 (so only 13 weeks ago).  I have tried to add "prune = 550" in bitcoin.conf and it said pruning in load but no avail.  Please advise what I can do e.g. increase foldersize (?) or steps of what to delete so I can reload the entire blockchain?
Thanks